# Hostname of Primary Name Server

Tags: dns, domain, domain-name, nameserver

I'm currently developing our town website that will be named `ourcityname.gov.ph`. Before I can register the domain name .gov.ph, I need to fill up a form. And here it is:
[image]

I'm stuck on this part. I do not know what will I put here if I will register on `hostgator`. Can anyone give a sample on what should I input there? I'm hoping for your kind consideration for my noob question. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you going to set up your own DNS server, or are you using one from a third party like your ISP? If you're using a third party one, there will usually be a control panel of some sort you can access via the web; they will usually list their name servers + IPs there.

Comment: @Seyren I will host it on hostgator, so it's a third party like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many web hosting providers, as well as most commercial domain registrars, provide DNS hosting to their customers. It's also possible to run your own, using software such as BIND or NSD.

It seems that HostGator also includes DNS hosting as part of the package (although with very limited functionality – they don't seem to provide any sort of manual record editing, which you would need if you wanted subdomains or email).

> … the welcome email which was sent when you signed up for web hosting will contain the name servers listed for your hosting account. These name servers can be used on all sites that are hosted on your HostGator webhosting account.
>
> — [What are my name servers?](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/hosting-guide/lets-get-started/dns-name-servers/what-are-my-name-servers)

---

You should give both the primary *and* secondary servers – it's good practice to have at least two DNS servers for a domain.

Entering just the server names should be enough. (The IP address fields would be required if the names were under the domain itself, e.g. `ns1.ourcityname.gov.ph`.)

Comment: Alright. This is perfect. Thank you! and lastly, in the part there where I should put something in the .GOV.PH DOMAIN NAME, should I put there ourcityname.gov.ph or www.ourcityname.gov.ph? Thank you!

Comment: @FewFlyBy: You're registering under `gov.ph`, therefore the domain name is just **`ourcityname.gov.ph`**. (The domain will be _delegated_ to whatever name servers you specify, and that automatically includes subdomains.)

Comment: In other words, all subdomains – everything to the left of `.ourcityname.gov.ph` – will be managed through your name servers (that is, HostGator). They do not need to be registered separately.

Comment: Alright, very much apprecaited. I only have one more question if it's okay. Since it's a government website, I am planning to get the business plan of hostgator because of the dedicated ip and everything. Should I also register this to cloudflare? Or do you have suggestions? Thank you.